# Foreach path found in variable remove-item

Tags: powershell

I'm having problem with removing files (Full path) in variable which should contain multiple paths. I have multiple installers, same program, different version in a folder. I want to keep the latest version and delete the older ones. I got this far but as you can probably see from the script, I'm not that experienced.

```
$InstallersLocs = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$DesktopPath\PS\Installers" -Recurse -Include *.exe | Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match 'Installer'} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object FullName |  Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Replace("FullName", "").Replace("--------", "").Trim()
  foreach ($InstallersLoc in $InstallersLocs) {
        Write-Output "Removing $InstallersLoc" 
      $Files += $InstallersLoc | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force
    }
```

Output from Write-output:

> ```
> Removing C:\Users\B\Desktop\PS\Installers\Installer Setup 1.0.1.exe
> C:\Users\B\Desktop\PS\Installers\Installer Setup 1.0.exe
> ```

I get these errors:

> ```
> Remove-Item : Illegal characters in path.
> At line:4 char:34
> +       $Files += $InstallersLoc | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force
> +                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Users\B\... Setup 1.0.exe:String) [Remove-Item], ArgumentException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
>
> Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\B\Desktop\PS\Installers\Installer Setup 1.0.1.exe
> ```

Comment: DO NOT use either `Format-Table` or `Out-String` if you want to use the objects later in a pipeline. they DO NOT return standard objects. it may look like what you think it should, but the `F-T` cmdlet has formatting code wrapped around the chopped up bits of your objects. the `0-S` cmdlet adds things like `cr/lf` chars to the `.ToString()` representation of the objects.

Comment: Thanks. Replacing `Select-Object FullName |  Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Replace("FullName", "").Replace("--------", "").Trim()` with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)` did the trick.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Please would you add the solution as answer, so the OP can accept? Otherwise, this will be yet another 'Unanswered' question in the list.

Comment: @Theo - i have posted an Answer ... but i am not pleased with it. [*sigh ...*] if you have suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you are having this problem is the ... unwanted ... characters added by both the `Format-*` and the `Out-String` cmdlets. remove those and use `Select-Object` with the `-ExpandProperty` parameter to get the value as a simple item.

you can see the "stuff" added by each of those two cmdlets by saving the output to a $Var and then looking at what is there.

for instance, the `[3]` item in what is returned by `Format-Table` gives you a red error text about ...

```
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData"
```

note the `Format` ... [*grin*]

if you send the stuff output by `Out-String` to `Format-Hex` you will see that it adds a leading `cr/lf` to the 1st line & another pair to the end of each line.

as a general rule, DO NOT use any of the `Format-*` cmdlets OR the `Out-String` cmdlet for anything other than *final* output to the screen OR *final* output to a plain text file.

Comment: Thanks. This may be easy enough for you to spot, but I see many questions where people try to pipe output through after Format-Table.. At least, now it is properly dealt with and marked answered. (+1)

Comment: @Theo - thank you for the review. i have ranted about the above cmdlets so often that i need to rein in my wrath when discussing them. i'm glad to know that i succeeded this time. [*grin*]